# JSF 2.1 Error Handling

Tags: jsf-2, error-handling

What is the proper way of handling errors in JSF 2.1? I've seen many posts which suggest different things but my guess is that most are for the previous version of JSF. I only need a basic error handling for displaying certain error pages for certain errors and a general error page for all other errors. What I found for 2.1 is putting the following in web.xml:

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/faces/error.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
```

Is this correct? What is the proper way of throwing an error? Is it with:

```
throw new WebApplicationException(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND);
```

Using the above method, the error propagates to the servlet and is it logged in the server. Is there a way to handle the error without throwing an exception which would propagate to the servlet?

Comment: `400 ad Request` is not the same as `404 Not Found`.

Comment: My bad. It should be 404. Fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

> *Is there a way to handle the error without throwing an exception which would propagate to the servlet?*

You can use [`ExternalContext#responseSendError()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#responseSendError%28int,%20java.lang.String%29) for that.

```
externalContext.responseSendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND, "some message");
facesContext.responseComplete();
```

Note that this is not specific to JSF 2.1. This applies as good to JSF 2.0 and older. Also note that this practice is in general not the normal practice of dealing with **exceptions** (as in, you actually caught one; the error page isn't a result of a failed precheck wherein no exception is been thrown at all). Normally, you'd just throw the exception and/or just let it go by redeclaring it as `throws` in the JSF action method and have the `<error-page><exception-type>` in `web.xml` to handle it. Only exception handling of JSF ajax requests requires a custom `ExceptionHandler` implementation, but that's a different story.

Comment: You say that this practice is not the normal practice. If the errors have to do with the internal functionality of the application and its business logic then should I use this method? Also, using responseSendError() doesn't it require an error page <error-page> in web.xml to handle that exception? So, isn't an exception still thrown by the application?

Comment: You were asking how to show an error page without throwing an exception. I just answered exactly that. It doesn't throw an exception at all. The custom `<error-page>` is not mandatory but nice to know/have when you'd like to provide a custom error page for a specific status code.